# File uploading rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I have a rails 3 app that has a comment system that allows a user to make comments. What I now wish to do is extend this further by enabling the user to attach/upload files to the comment system. Fairly easy question I am about to ask. What is the best tool/plugin or gem to use so that I can achieve this? I've done some thorough research and found that alot of these plugins such as carrierwave, paperclip and a few others are used to upload photos and I am not trying to do this.

Requirements

- User should be able to upload/attach files
- Can upload word, powerpoint or execel docuements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both carrierwave and paperclip can be used to upload any type of files - they have extra features if you want to upload images, but they are not restricted to handling just image files.
In the end it's a matter of preference. I found both paperclip and carrierwave to be very good at what they do.

Comment: What I don't seem to understand is where are the files stored?

Comment: +1 for CarrierWave.  This honestly is one of the things that has always turned me off about PaperClip.  Sure you can write processors for anything, but something about the attachment invocation mixing styles and thumb into the arguments does tend to make it "feel" like it's really intended for images.

Comment: @djj both gems support multiple storage backends, commonly s3 and your filesystem.

Comment: My next question is would it be possible to use carrierwave to attach a file to a comment?

Comment: Sure, check the docs, but you'd generate an uploader (say CommentFileUploader), then mount it to your Comment model, then throw a file field in your comment form.  `class Comment; mount_uploader :file, CommentFileUploader end`

Answer (score 2):

[Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

[CarrierWave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

As for me CarrierWave more modern and nice solution. Have a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use even dragonfly - https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/